# Right way to strip tags except some in python

Tags: python, html

For example, i have HTML code, where contains codes like this

```
<a href="some" class="some" onclick="return false;">anchor</a>
<table id="some">
    <tr>
        <td class="some">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p class="" style="">content</p>
```

And i want remove all tags attributes and save only some tags (for example, remove table, tr, tr, th tags), so, i want get something like this.

```
<a href="some">anchor</a>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>content</p>
```

I do it using for loop, but my code retrieves each tag and cleans it. I think that my way slow.

What you can suggest me? Thanks.

**Update #1**

In my solution i use this code for removing tags (stealed from django)

```
def remove_tags(html, tags):
    """Returns the given HTML with given tags removed."""
    tags = [re.escape(tag) for tag in tags.split()]
    tags_re = '(%s)' % '|'.join(tags)
    starttag_re = re.compile(r'<%s(/?>|(\s+[^>]*>))' % tags_re, re.U)
    endtag_re = re.compile('</%s>' % tags_re)
    html = starttag_re.sub('', html)
    html = endtag_re.sub('', html)
    return html
```

And this code to clean HTML attributes

```
# But this code doesnt remove empty tags (without content ant etc.) like this `<div><img></div>`
import lxml.html.clean

html = 'Some html code'

safe_attrs = lxml.html.clean.defs.safe_attrs
cleaner = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(safe_attrs_only=True, safe_attrs=frozenset())
html = cleaner.clean_html(html)
```

Comment: If you want feedback, share your code.

Comment: @user590028, i add my code to question.

Comment: You say "i want remove all tags attributes" and then your example output starts with `<a href="some">` where `href` of course **is** a tag attribute.  This makes your request contradictory and thus impossible to satisfy.  Please edit the question to remove the contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Use [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```
html = """
<a href="some" class="some" onclick="return false;">anchor</a>
<table id="some">
    <tr>
        <td class="some">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p class="" style="">content</p>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

del soup.table.tr.td.attrs 
del soup.table.attrs 
print(soup.prettify())

<html>
 <body>
  <a class="some" href="some" onclick="return false;">
   anchor
  </a>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <p class="" style="">
   content
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

To clear tags:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.table.clear()
print(soup.prettify())

<html>
 <body>
  <a class="some" href="some" onclick="return false;">
   anchor
  </a>
  <table id="some">
  </table>
  <p class="" style="">
   content
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

To delete particulat attribute:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

td_tag =  soup.table.td
del td_tag['class']
print(soup.prettify())

<html>
 <body>
  <a class="some" href="some" onclick="return false;">
   anchor
  </a>
  <table id="some">
   <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <p class="" style="">
   content
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In any way, using BeautifulSoup is very slow way, insted of BeautifulSoup i using `lxml`. And in yours example i see, that for each tag element, that i want to clean, i must set it to `None`.

Comment: I use re only for removing tags.

Comment: @AlexAntonov, how much time does it take?

Comment: Code that i pasted above executes a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called parsing.

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is one of most popular / most used libraries for parsing html.
You can use it to remove tags and it is pretty well [documented](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Removing%20elements).

If you (because of some reason) can not use BeautifulSoup then look into python `re` module.

Comment: For cleaning and parsing HTML, i use only `lxml` and `re`, because BS4 is very slow decision.